Adding semicolon symbol ";" to the value of element
I have variable "cond_in" as a "document-node" type. For example,
    <entry attribute1="att1", attribute2="att2">
        <p>Value1</p>
        <p>Value2</p>
        <p>Value3</p>
    </entry>

In result, I want to create the variable "cond_out" as a "document-node" type, but add to each  element "; " string:
    <entry attribute1="att1", attribute2="att2">
        <p>Value1; </p>
        <p>Value2; </p>
        <p>Value3; </p>
    </entry>

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance!
I tried the following:
    <xsl:variable name="cond_out">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$cond_in" mode="addsymbol"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="entry" mode="addsymbol">
        <xsl:copy-of select="entry"/>
    </xsl:template>

I don't know how to add this semicolon ";" to the value of the element ....

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

A template <xsl:template match="entry/p"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="concat(., '; ')"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template> should do the job to transform the p elements, of course you need to make sure you push your nodes through templates with xsl:apply-templates and have the identity transformation template set up to copy everything else unchanged.
You can see the complete XSLT 3 solution (declaring <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>) at this online fiddle.
The result there, for the input
<entry attribute1="att1" attribute2="att2">
        <p>Value1</p>
        <p>Value2</p>
        <p>Value3</p>
</entry>

is
<entry attribute1="att1" attribute2="att2">
        <p>Value1; </p>
        <p>Value2; </p>
        <p>Value3; </p>
</entry>

If you really use an XSLT 2 processor then replace the xsl:mode declaration with the identity transformation template
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


Hello Martin, thank you for your answer. But the result is a bit different, than I expected. The result is, without element  and -elements has no sub-elements. For example, the source:
<entry attribute1="att1", attribute2="att2">
Value1
Value2
Value3
Test1

I need to have:
<entry attribute1="att1", attribute2="att2">
Value1;
Value2;
Test1;

But I have the following result:
Value1;
Value2;
Test1;
@Shud, I am not sure whether you have understood the advice "to make sure you push your nodes through templates with xsl:apply-templates and have the identity transformation template set up to copy everything else unchanged", I have edited and extended the answer on how the suggested template is supposed to be integrated in a complete stylesheet.
